# Python - index error in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am Writing Program that takes an input 2 thins 1st direction & 2nd is steps in one line, i am doing this by using split(' ') all these input takes in while loop
but user dont want to entry more input he just enter the blank line and terminate but it is not happening dont know why... this is my code

```
while True:
movement = input().split(' ')
direction = movement[0].lower()
step = int(movement[1])
if movement != '' or movement != 0:

    if direction == 'up' or direction == 'down':
        if y == 0:
            if direction == 'down':
                y -= step
            else:
                y += step
        else:
            if direction == 'down':
                y -= step
            else:
                y += step
    elif direction == 'left' or direction == 'right':
        if x == 0:
            if direction == 'right':
                x -= step
            else:
                x += step
        else:
            if direction == 'right':
                x -= step
            else:
                x += step
else:
    current = (x, y)
    print(original)
    print(current)
    break
```

but i enter bank input it shows this message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Zohaib/PycharmProjects/Python Assignments/Question_14.py", 
 line 04, in <module>
 step = int(movement[1])
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: *but user dont want to entry more input he just enter the blank line and terminate*. So what do you think what happens when you try to use `movement.split()` on an empty line? How many elements will that create in the resulting list?

Comment: Sidetrack a bit, but why do you need to add an if x == 0 statement since the code to be executed is the same in both if and else (same for the y as well)

Comment: i want when user no more entries he just enter the blank line and loop terminates

Comment: When blank input is given, `movement[0]` will be null and nothing is assigned to `movement[1]`

Comment: to elaborate on what @MartijnPieters said, you could just print ``movement`` right after ``movement = input().split(' ')`` and you will see what your list looks like (and how many elements it has).

Comment: before while loop, I declare y & x because make its scope to entire program

Comment: @voidpro: `movement[0]` will be the empty string, not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a len() of your list and if you don't get any movement you make any logic, for example

```
if len(movement) == 0:
    # Your logic when you don't have any input
    pass
else:
    # Your logic when you have at least one input
    pass
```

Comment: Does not work for this case. ``print(len("".split(' ')))`` is ``1`` (because the list has 1 element - an empty string)!

Comment: i use this condition len(movement) == 1: break

Answer (score 0):

Move your direction = movement[0].lower() lines into the if statement, this will allow them to run only if movement != '', you need to change your if statement o and instead otherwise it is always true as movement can't be '' and 0 at the same time

Also, move the split into the if statement as well, so that when comparing in the if statement, just comparing movement. (' '.split() returns [])

```
while True:

    movement = input()
    if movement != '' and movement != '0':
        movement = movement.split()
        direction = movement[0].lower()
        step = int(movement[1])
        del movement[1]
        if direction == 'up' or direction == 'down':
            if y == 0:
                if direction == 'down':
                    y -= step
                else:
                    y += step
            else:
                if direction == 'down':
                    y -= step
                else:
                    y += step
        elif direction == 'left' or direction == 'right':
            if x == 0:
                if direction == 'right':
                    x -= step
                else:
                    x += step
            else:
                if direction == 'right':
                    x -= step
                else:
                    x += step
    else:
        current = (x, y)
        print(original)
        print(current)
        break
```